# Contao module - main screen (No Query) with subscreens

Tags: php, module, contao

I've been following the cd_collection tutorial so far but realized that I won't be able to realize my module in a backend user friendly manner. Basically I need three tables that should be editable on their own:

> tl_elementType

Contains all possible types for the elements (Name, tstamp and id)

> tl_elementManufacturer

Contains manufacturers for the elements (Name, tstamp and id)

> tl_elements

Contains a name and the type and manufacturer as references. In the backend, I want these to show up as dropdowns.

Do I have to make modules for each table or can I add flat pages with links to modules somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this problem: I suggest using two instead of three tables. Using the first to save your topmost categories and using the latter to store their children. It'll leave you with a bit of fumbling to do but it will work.

Answer (score -1):

I strongly advice that you follow this tutorial http://blog.qzminski.com/article/create-a-custom-module-the-basics.html.

I bet you have a reason to have chosen to learn Contao and if that is the case, doing things the Contao way will give you a better position in future to implement complex apps. BTW Welcome to Contao. Its great doing things with it.

Its the best way to realize what you want then you can adopt to your module. Learn first before implementing anything.